# whats the difference between " variances of frequency counts in grey levels " and "variances of all pixel values"

Tags: image-processing, statistics

i read some article about quality assessment and one of it's proposed techniques was to classify the image into three categories. "smooth" "texture" and "edge". the article told that we should calculate these variances for features. i dont know the difference between these two.

Answer (score 1):

Although this is not really a good question for SO, because it's not related to programming. I can try to answer to give you a guide and suggest you look for more information on another site. For example [dsp.stackexchange.com](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/)

The "variance of frequency counts in grey levels" is effectively the variance of the greyscale histogram of the image. This give you an indication of the way that different intensity levels are present in the image but says nothing about the position of these grey levels, although a bi-modal (or multi-modal) histogram does indicate the presence of "features" of some kind.

The "variance of all pixel values" is the variance of the image itself, which is not the same thing. This gives an indication of the texture of the image as a high variance indicates a large number of edges (i.e. high frequency content) and a low variance indicates a "smoother" texture. So this measure *is* dependent on the positions of the pixels as well as their grey levels.

Take a look [at this related question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/30064), which gives some good examples of the differences.